# how to select the value of 'many2many_checkboxes' with python code

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10

i'm trying to change product route depending on some condition but i'm having hard time figuring out how to check and select the value of this many2many_checkbox with python code ,is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to update many2many fields with python code http://www.odooninja.com/update-many2many-field/